# auto multi-level tree with cypher

Tags: tree, neo4j, cypher

I'm currently having this Neo4j schema: one node is linked to another by a relationship "CONTENTS". Let's say i don't know how much levels i will have.

For now, i have this query :

```
MATCH (p:Keyword) 
    OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:CONTENTS]->(p1) 
    OPTIONAL MATCH (p1)-[:CONTENTS]->(p2) 
    OPTIONAL MATCH (p2)-[:CONTENTS]->(p3)
    OPTIONAL MATCH (p3)-[:CONTENTS]->(p4)
        WITH p,p1,p2,p3,{uid: p4.uid, name: p4.name} as child4
        WITH p,p1,p2,{uid: p3.uid, name: p3.name , children: collect(child4)} as child3
        WITH p,p1,{uid: p2.uid, name: p2.name , children: collect(child3)} as child2
        WITH p,{uid: p1.uid, name: p1.name , children: collect(child2)} as child1
                WITH {uid: p.uid, name: p.name, children: collect(child1)} as child
RETURN {tree: collect(child)}
```

The results are what i need but with this way, i limit my results to 5 levels. Without adding more "OPTIONAL MATCH", how can i set this query automatically multi-level ?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't completely understand what the desired output of your query should be.

You need to use a variable path length match by amending the relationship specification with a quantifier `*<lower>..<upper>`:

```
MATCH path=(p:Keyword)-[:CONTENTS*0..5]->(content) // match 0 to 5 CONTENTS hops
RETURN path, length(path) as len
ORDER BY len desc
LIMIT 1   // only proceed with longest path
```

EDIT:

```
MATCH path=(p:Keyword)-[:CONTENTS*0..4]->(content)-[:CONTENTS]->(child) 
RETURN content.uid, collect(child.uid) as children
```

Comment: For having the complete tree, i'm doing like this. But in this case, i want an hierarchical output. Each "parent" must be having a "children" sub-array.
For example :

[{"uid":"1","name":"name 1","children":[{"uid":"2","name":" name 2"},{"uid":"3","name":" name 3","children":[{"uid":"4","name":" name 4"},{"uid":"5","name":" name 5"},{"uid":"6","name":" name 6","children":[{"uid":"7","name":" name 7"}]}]}]}]

Comment: Thanks... but the output doesn't show sublevels... (for each "level", i imagine i need a "collect" for his sublevel)

Comment: isn't level == length(path) ?

Comment: length(path) seems to set all childrens (and sub*-childrens) at the same level. For the first level, "children" = all the direct children + children of thoses + children of thoses + ... I just want thoses informations keeped in hierarchical order like my first query...

Comment: don't quite get it. Maybe share a sample dataset using http://console.neo4j.org and describe the desired result?

Comment: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=eycvuq

this is an example with the json-output i need...

Comment: I think you might be easier off returning the data like stefan suggested and building the tree in your client language.